# Why are templated copy constructors ignored?

Tags: c++

I think this code should print "hit" but it doesn't. If you comment out line 6 (the template line), it prints "hit."

```
#include <iostream>

struct test {
    test() {}

    template<typename = typename std::enable_if<true>::type>
    test(test const & other) {
        std::cout << "hit";
    }
};

int main()
{
  test a;
  test b(a);
}
```

The standard explicitly indicates this. What's the rationale?

Comment: I tested this in Visual Studio 2017 and https://cpp.sh

Comment: Maybe because the template function is not a copy constructor, but something masquerading as one?  AFAIK, the standard doesn't define the canonical copy constructor as a function that is templated.  OK, the duplicate verified my suspicions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9487897/1848654

Comment: When compiler has to choose between free-function (default copy ctor generated by compiler) and templated ctor (both have the same match), always free-function is called. You can see `hit` only if you remove `const` from signature of templated ctor because `template<> test(test&)` is better match when it is called for non-const object `test a;` than calling default copy ctor  which takes `test` by const reference.

Comment: Is constructor inheritance a possible workaround? Two base classes, one has the constructor, one does not, and which is inherited is determined through template resolution.

Comment: @Brent What are you trying to accomplish with this?  There is probably an already existing workaround

Comment: I have a wrapper class that's templated on a type T. The wrapper class should only be copy constructible if T is.

Comment: Does the class hold a `T`.  If so you already get this.  If `T` is not copyable it will automatically mark the wrappers copy constructor as deleted.  This is how `std::vector` works.  A `std::vector<int>` is copyable but a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` isn't.

Comment: It only holds a T through a pointer. More importantly, if a copy is permitted, the default copy constructor doesn't have the needed behavior.

Comment: I think another work around might be to have a new class that when copied carries out the needed operations. Add an instance of this class to the wrapper, and let the default copy constructor do its thing. Put a T in the wrapper class to control whether that default copy constructor is created.

Comment: @Brent You could also specialize the entire class.  Take a look at this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40807e3483fc075e