# Why SFINAE doesnt work here

Tags: c++, sfinae

I want to implement static check to find out if type constructible:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct IsConstr
{
    typedef char TrueType;
    typedef struct{char a[2];} FalseType;
    template<typename C>
    static decltype((C(),TrueType())) test(int);
    template<typename C>
    static FalseType test(...);

    enum{value=(sizeof(test<T>(0))==sizeof(TrueType))};
}; 


struct S{private: S();};
int main()
{
    std::cout<<IsConstr<S>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<IsConstr<int>::value<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code doesn't compile, showing an error

> "Substitution failed. 'S::S()' is private".

Why doesn't SFINAE work here?
Thanks.

Comment: You might be intrested in reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984013/can-sfinae-detect-private-access-violations/8984379#8984379 (btw. clang likes your code)

Comment: It compiles with clang 3.0-6ubuntu3, it does not with g++ 4.7.2-2ubuntu1

Comment: Weren't some SFINAE functionality disabled by C++11?

Comment: It's a bug, g++ doesn't compile even `std::is_default_constructible`.

Comment: Good to know that bug is in gcc, not in my code. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this also compiles with gcc from svn

Comment: It works in modern compilers: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1fWxn64qM