# protected members in a template deduction context: compilation error, substitution fails, or succeeds?

Tags: c++11, g++, clang, access-modifiers, sfinae

g++ 5.2.1 fails to compile when it encounters a private method's address in a template deduction context whereas clang 3.5 only discards the specialization.
g++ 5.2.1 can access protected members of parents/friends in a class template parameter list when clang 3.5 sometimes fail to do so.
Which are wrong in which cases?

More precisely:

- Should the compiler cause a hard error when trying to access a non accessible protected/private member in a template deduction context? Am I doing something wrong in my first example?
- If not, should the compiler discard a specialization when trying to access (in a template deduction context) a protected member owned by:

  - a base class of this specific specialization
  - a class which declared this specific instantiation as a friend
  - a friend class which declared any instantiation of this template as a friend

The first question seems to have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984013/can-sfinae-detect-private-access-violations) (and the answer seems to be "no, the code isn't ill-formed and the compiler should simply discard this specialization").  However, since it's a prerequisite to the second question (and g++ 5.2.1 doesn't seem to agree), I want to be absolutely sure that it's g++ 5.2.1 which is wrong, not me.

---

## Longer version with examples

I would like to make traits able to detect whether some functions/methods are implemented, even if they are protected members of some class (if you find this odd, I'll explain why I want to do this at the end of this question so that you can tell me I'm completely wrong, should learn how to design my classes, and maybe suggest me a cleaner way to do so).
My problem is that each of my attempts fail on either clang or g++ (oddly enough, not both at the same time): Sometimes it compiles but don't provide the expected result, sometimes it doesn't compile at all.
Even though it seems it isn't practical, I at least want to know when the compilers are faulty, and when I'm writing ill-formed code. Hence this question.

I use the C++11 dialect, and my clang version is actually the compiler provided with XCode 5 i.e. Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn).

To better illustrate what my problem is, here is a minimal exemple where clang compiles but g++ 5.2.1 doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct PrivateFoo {
private:
  void foo() {}
};

/* utilities */

// reimplement C++17's std::void_t
template<class...>
struct void_type {
  typedef void type;
};

template<class... T>
using void_t = typename void_type<T...>::type;

// dummy class used to check whether a pointer to (possibly member) function
// exists with the good signature
template<class T, T>
struct check_signature {};

/* traits */

template<class C, class = void>
struct has_foo : std::false_type {};

template<class C>
struct has_foo<C, void_t<check_signature<void(C::*)(), &C::foo>>> :
std::true_type {};

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "PrivateFoo has foo: " << has_foo<PrivateFoo>::value << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

output with clang 3.5:

```
PrivateFoo has foo: false
```

g++ 5.2.1 errors:

```
access_traits.cpp : [in instantiation of] ‘struct has_foo<PrivateFoo>’ :
access_traits.cpp:37:61:   required from here
access_traits.cpp:7:8: [error]: ‘void PrivateFoo::foo()’ is private
   void foo() {}
        ^
access_traits.cpp:32:56: [error]: [in context]
 struct has_foo<C, void_t<check_signature<void(C::*)(), &C::foo>>> :
                                                        ^
access_traits.cpp:7:8: [error]: ‘void PrivateFoo::foo()’ is private
   void foo() {}
        ^
access_traits.cpp:32:56: [error]: [in context]
 struct has_foo<C, void_t<check_signature<void(C::*)(), &C::foo>>> :
                                                        ^
access_traits.cpp: [in function] ‘int main()’:
access_traits.cpp:7:8: erreur: ‘void PrivateFoo::foo()’ is private
   void foo() {}
        ^
access_traits.cpp:37:42: [error]: [in context]
   std::cout << "PrivateFoo has foo: " << has_foo<PrivateFoo>::value << '\n';
```

(text in brackets is translated, it was originally in my native language)

Here is an example where both compile but disagree on whether `foo` is accessible or not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct ProtectedFoo {
protected:
  void foo() {}
};

/* utilities */

// reimplement C++17's std::void_t
template<class...>
struct void_type {
  typedef void type;
};

template<class... T>
using void_t = typename void_type<T...>::type;

// dummy class used to check whether a pointer to (possibly member) function
// exists with the good signature
template<class T, T>
struct check_signature {};

/* traits */

namespace detail {
  template<class C, class = void>
  struct has_foo_helper : std::false_type {};

  template<class C>
  struct has_foo_helper<C, void_t<decltype(std::declval<C>().foo())>> :
  std::true_type {};
}

template<class C>
struct has_public_or_protected_foo : protected C {
  template<class, class>
  friend class detail::has_foo_helper;

  static constexpr bool value =
  detail::has_foo_helper<has_public_or_protected_foo<C>>::value;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "ProtectedFoo has foo: ";
  std::cout << has_public_or_protected_foo<ProtectedFoo>::value << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

output with clang 3.5:

```
ProtectedFoo has foo: false
```

output with g++ 5.2.1:

```
ProtectedFoo has foo: true
```

and finally here is an example where both compile and agree that they should be able to access `foo`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct ProtectedFoo {
protected:
  void foo() {}
};

/* utilities */

// reimplement C++17's std::void_t
template<class...>
struct void_type {
  typedef void type;
};

template<class... T>
using void_t = typename void_type<T...>::type;

// dummy class used to check whether a pointer to (possibly member) function
// exists with the good signature
template<class T, T>
struct check_signature {};

/* traits */

namespace detail {
  template<class C, class D, class = void>
  struct has_foo_helper : std::false_type {};

  template<class C, class D>
  struct has_foo_helper<C, D, void_t<check_signature<void(C::*)(), &D::foo>>> :
  std::true_type {};
}

template<class C>
struct has_public_or_protected_foo : protected C {
  template<class, class, class>
  friend class detail::has_foo_helper;

  static constexpr bool value =
  detail::has_foo_helper<C, has_public_or_protected_foo<C>>::value;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "ProtectedFoo has foo: ";
  std::cout << has_public_or_protected_foo<ProtectedFoo>::value << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

output with clang 3.5:

```
ProtectedFoo has foo: true
```

output with g++ 5.2.1:

```
ProtectedFoo has foo: true
```

Also here is a more complete example which summarizes it all:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

/* test classes */

struct PublicFoo {
  void foo() {}
};

struct ProtectedFoo {
protected:
  void foo() {}
};

struct PrivateFoo {
private:
  void foo() {}
};

struct NoFoo {};

/* utilities */

// reimplement C++17's std::void_t
template<class...>
struct void_type {
  typedef void type;
};

template<class... T>
using void_t = typename void_type<T...>::type;

// dummy class used to check whether a pointer to (possibly member) function
// exists with the good signature
template<class T, T>
struct check_signature {};

/* traits */

namespace detail {
  template<class C, class D, class = void>
  struct has_foo_helper : std::false_type {};

  template<class C, class D>
  struct has_foo_helper<C, D, void_t<check_signature<void(C::*)(), &D::foo>>> :
  std::true_type {};

  template<class C, class = void>
  struct may_call_foo_helper : std::false_type {};

  template<class C>
  struct may_call_foo_helper<C, void_t<decltype(std::declval<C>().foo())>> :
  std::true_type {};
}

template<class C>
struct has_foo : detail::has_foo_helper<C, C> {};

template<class C>
struct may_call_foo : detail::may_call_foo_helper<C> {};

template<class C>
struct has_protected_foo : protected C {
  template<class, class, class>
  friend class detail::has_foo_helper;

  static constexpr bool value =
  detail::has_foo_helper<C, has_protected_foo<C>>::value;
};

template<class C>
struct may_call_protected_foo : protected C {
  template<class, class>
  friend class detail::may_call_foo_helper;

  static constexpr bool value =
  detail::may_call_foo_helper<may_call_protected_foo<C>>::value;
};

/* test */

template<class T>
void print_info(const char* classname) {
  std::cout << classname << "...\n";
  // comment this if you want to compile with g++
  //*
  std::cout << "has a public method \"void foo()\": ";
  std::cout << has_foo<T>::value << '\n';
  std::cout << "has a public or protected method \"void foo()\": ";
  std::cout << has_protected_foo<T>::value << '\n';
  //*/
  std::cout << "has a public method \"foo\" callable without any arguments: ";
  std::cout << may_call_foo<T>::value << '\n';
  std::cout << "has a public or protected method \"foo\" callable without any "
               "arguments: ";
  std::cout << may_call_protected_foo<T>::value << '\n';
  std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  // both g++ 5.2.1 and clang 3.5 compile
  print_info<PublicFoo>("PublicFoo");
  // g++ 5.2.1 fails to compile has_foo, clang 3.5 compiles fine
  print_info<ProtectedFoo>("ProtectedFoo");
  // g++ 5.2.1 fails to compile, clang 3.5 compiles fine
  print_info<PrivateFoo>("PrivateFoo");
  // both g++ 5.2.1 and clang 3.5 compile
  print_info<NoFoo>("NoFoo");
  return 0;
}
```

---

## Why do I want to do this?

Skip this if you don't want to know the details. I just wrote this in case you were either shocked by the idea of me trying to detect protected members and/or curious about why I asked this question.

I was writing some kind of iterator template classes built out of other iterators and I got tired of writing multiple specializations depending on whether these iterators meet some requirements (ForwardIterator, BidirectionalIterator, RandomAccessIterator... although my iterators actually meet some relaxed versions of these concepts, they are kind of "proxy iterators" but it's not really relevant here).
For instance, if I only use random access iterators, my new custom iterator could (and should) also be some kind of random access iterator, hence implement `operator+=`, `operator+`, `operator-=`, `operator-`, `operator<`, `operator>`, `operator<=` and `operator>=`. However, some of these operators can easily be deduced from others, and they should only be defined if all the iterator I use are random access iterators.

I finally thought I'd just make something to provide default implementations if available. However, I wasn't really fond of the `std::allocator_traits` way as it wouldn't be very handy and readable with iterators (plus, I wouldn't be able to use them with some standard utilities).
The design I finally choose consists in having a template class which will build a full-fledged iterator out of a minimal implementation (for instance containing only the `operator+=`, `operator==`, `operator*` and `operator>` definitions) by having an inheritance chain of "mixins" (whose ancestor is my minimal iterator) detecting whether the functions/methods they need are available in their base class and defining the default methods if they are.
There is a subtility though. Sometimes I want to return a reference to the final iterator (for instance in `Iterator& operator++()`). If it's a method I redefine, I can easily solve that with CRTP and a `static_cast`, but what if my mixins don't touch that method at all?
I figured I should probably forbid the use of any method I haven't touched and inherit my minimal iterator with the protected access specifier... but now then my traits fail to detect the availability of some protected methods.
Therefore, I'd like to have traits able to detect whether some members are available with either public or protected visibility.

Comment: Your first example is definitely https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61806

Comment: I would like the answer to this as well.