# C++ Detect private member of friend class with CRTP

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits, crtp, enable-if

I have a CRTP Base class (*Bar*) which is inherited by a unspecified class. This Derived class may or may not have specific member (*internal_foo*), and this specific member my or may not have another member (*test()*).

In this scenario *internal_foo* will always be public, however *test()* is private, but declaring *Bar* as a friend.

I can detect *internal_foo* using traits fine, because it is public. But I cannot detect *test()* due to it being private, even though *Bar* is a friend.

The below example works due to *test()* being public:

```
template<class, class = void >
struct has_internal_foo : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_internal_foo<T,
    void_t<
    decltype(std::declval<T>().internal_foo)
    >> : std::true_type {};

template<class, class = void>
struct internal_foo_has_test : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct internal_foo_has_test<T,
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().internal_foo.test())
    >> : std::true_type {};

class InternalFoo
{
public:

    void test()
    {

    }
};

class BadInternalFoo
{
};

template<class T>
class Bar
{
public:
    template<class _T = T>
    std::enable_if_t<conjunction<has_internal_foo<_T>, internal_foo_has_test<_T>>::value, void>
        action()
    {
        static_cast<T&>(*this).internal_foo.test();
    }
};

class Foo : 
    public Bar<Foo>
{
public:
    InternalFoo internal_foo;
};

class BadFoo :
    public Bar<BadFoo>
{
public:
    BadInternalFoo internal_foo;
};

void test()
{
    Foo foo;
    BadFoo bad_foo;

    foo.action(); // Compiles. As expected.
    bad_foo.action(); // Does not compile. As expected.
}
```

However this next version does not work, due to *test()* being private:

```
template<class, class = void >
struct has_internal_foo : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_internal_foo<T,
    void_t<
    decltype(std::declval<T>().internal_foo)
    >> : std::true_type {};

template<class, class = void>
struct internal_foo_has_test : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct internal_foo_has_test<T,
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().internal_foo.test())
    >> : std::true_type {};

class InternalFoo
{
public:
    template<class T>
    friend class Bar;

    template<class, class>
    friend struct internal_foo_has_test;

private:
    void test()
    {

    }
};

class BadInternalFoo
{
};

template<class T>
class Bar
{
public:
    template<class _T = T>
    std::enable_if_t<conjunction<has_internal_foo<_T>, internal_foo_has_test<_T>>::value, void>
        action()
    {
        static_cast<T&>(*this).internal_foo.test();
    }
};

class Foo : 
    public Bar<Foo>
{
public:
    InternalFoo internal_foo;
};

class BadFoo :
    public Bar<BadFoo>
{
public:
    BadInternalFoo internal_foo;
};

void test()
{
    Foo foo;
    BadFoo bad_foo;

    foo.action(); // Does not compile
    bad_foo.action(); // Does not compile
}
```

As seen above, I have tried to friend the detection struct too, but that didn't help.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?

Ideally I would like this solution to be portable, and not use anything beyond C++11, 14 at the most. (I have implemented void_t & conjunction)

Edit:

The suggested question does not answer this one. That question wants to detect whether a member is public or private, and only access it if it is public, I wish for the detection to return *positive* on a private member of a friend class.

Comment: If you just need conditional compilation on `action`, get rid of member detection and make `action` return `decltype(static_cast<T&>(*this).internal_foo.test())` instead of `enable_if_t`s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test access to a private function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775029/how-to-test-access-to-a-private-function)

Comment: Aren't you using GCC  by any chance? Does your code work with Clang?

Comment: @yeputons: Thank you! I have even used that technique before, but I don't know why it didn't come to me this time. I am using Visual Studio 2019 right now, but I use GCC on Linux with the same code base, hence the portability.

Comment: It seems that private members and friends [play weirdly with SFINAE](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/09/10/friend-access-inconsistencies/).

Comment: There was also a bug in gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96204. That is fixed in gcc 12 ( hopefully :-) ).

Comment: Ahh yes, that issue with SFINAE under *Divergence on friend with templates* is pretty much exactly what I was butting up against.

Comment: Here is a shorter example of different behavior by GCC and Clang: https://godbolt.org/z/T17dG3Mx1. Moreover, commenting out one of `static_assert`s in it makes GCC accept the code. Weird stuff.

Comment: @yeputons: That is fixed also in gcc 12... maybe it is related to my previous command ( bugreport for gcc ). Simply use gcc 12 on godbolt, seams to work now!

Comment: @yeputons that is definitely weird behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary and the fix

Looks like a GCC 11 bug and your second attempt should in fact work.

However, I recommend rewriting `action`'s definition in either of two ways so you don't even need the member detection idiom:

```cpp
// Way 1
template<class _T = T>
decltype(std::declval<_T&>().internal_foo.test()) action() {
    static_cast<T&>(*this).internal_foo.test();
}

// Way 1, with a different return type via the comma operator
template<class _T = T>
decltype(std::declval<_T&>().internal_foo.test(), std::declval<ReturnType>()) action() {
    static_cast<T&>(*this).internal_foo.test();
}

// Way 2
template<class _T = T>
auto action() -> decltype(static_cast<_T&>(*this).internal_foo.test()) {
    static_cast<_T&>(*this).internal_foo.test();  // Using _T for consistency
}
```

Note that I use `_T` inside the `decltype` so it's dependent on the template argument and can be SFINAEd. Also note that it's still possible to specify an arbitrary return return type without any `enable_if`s.

### Details

I took the liberty to prepend `#include <type_traits>` and `using namespace std;` to both of your examples and using C++17 so they can be compiled.

Some findings from the comments section:

1. Your first code (does not) compile(s) as expected with Clang 14, gcc 11 and gcc trunk: https://godbolt.org/z/EbaYvfPE3
2. Your second code (does not) compile(s) as expected with Clang add gcc trunk, but gcc 11 differs: https://godbolt.org/z/bbKrP8Mb9

There is an easier reproduction example: https://godbolt.org/z/T17dG3Mx1

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<class, class = void>
struct has_test : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_test<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().test())>> : std::true_type {};

class HasPrivateTest
{
public:
    template<class, class>
    friend struct has_test;
    friend void foo();

private:
    void test() {}
};

// Comment the following line to make it compile with GCC 11
static_assert(has_test<HasPrivateTest>::value, "");
void foo() {
    static_assert(has_test<HasPrivateTest>::value, "");
}
static_assert(has_test<HasPrivateTest>::value, "");
```

The code above compiles with Clang 14 and gcc trunk, but is rejected by gcc 11 with three "static assertion failed" messages, one for each assertion. However, commenting out the first `static_assert` makes all three compilers accept the code.

So it seems like GCC 11 (and earlier) tries to instantiate the template and do access checks depending on the context. Hence, if the first instantiation is outside of a friend, `.test()` method is not accessible, and the result is kind cached. However, if it's inside the `friend void foo()`, `.test()` is accessible and all `static_assert`s succeed.

@Klaus have pointed out a recent GCC bug whose fix seems relevant: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96204

Comment: More or less with the same SFINAE stuff i was not successful which was the reason to fill the bug report. But I switched to concepts for such use cases... much easier to read I believe.