# SFINAE not detecting private access violations (compiler specific error)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae

According to [Can SFINAE detect private access violations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984013/can-sfinae-detect-private-access-violations), SFINAE should detect private access violations. However, the following example which checks whether a class includes a member passes even if that member should be inaccessible (as it is declared as private) using Visual C++ 2022:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename, typename = void>
struct has_member_foo : std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct has_member_foo<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::foo_)>> : std::true_type {};


class TestWithPrivateFooMember
{
private:
    int foo_;
};

int main()
{
    // Should be false but evaluates to true with Visual Studio 2022 and compiles just fine...
    static_assert(has_member_foo<TestWithPrivateFooMember>::value);
}

// Compiled with Visual C++ 2022 using the command line:
// cl.exe  /nologo /TP  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -std:c++20 /FS -c main.cpp
```

Could it be a Visual C++ bug?

The static assertion should raise a compilation error.

Comment: Gcc and Clang are failing on this assertion: https://godbolt.org/z/b9s51q3xh

Comment: Here is version which respects "private"s and works same everywhere: https://godbolt.org/z/zzzsM1jjo but I'm not sure who is right in your example.

Comment: One character different to your example and also works as desired: https://godbolt.org/z/dfhj5f6s1 - so I'm leaning to your claim this is MSVC bug.

Comment: BTW you have poor test coverage. Note special cases here https://godbolt.org/z/M9Gc6shzz you should take into account.

Comment: side note: given that you have c++20 available, you can also consider using concepts. `template <typename T>
concept has_foo = requires (T t) { {t.foo_}; };`

Comment: This looks very wrong so here's a [bugreport](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Access-to-private-member-in-type-trait-p/10590296?q=Access+to+private+member+in+type+trait&ref=native&refTime=1708361708546&refUserId=212cf051-8e85-459b-8a31-fa05d00d44a6) to vote on if you want it to be fixed :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was about to submit the same.